# How to select this HTML Text in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The HTML text:
`<div data-v-4b11382c="" class="text-2xl font-bold font-numeric" xpath="1">0,00</div>`

Things that doesnt work:

```
timer_t = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='text-2xl font-bold font-numeric'])[1]").text
timer_t = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".text-2xl.font-bold.font-numeric").text
```

Website with the element "https://csgoempire.com/"
Its the Countdown

Answer (score 0):

You have to use explicit wait

```
driver.get("https://csgoempire.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".text-2xl.font-bold.font-numeric")))
timer_t = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".text-2xl.font-bold.font-numeric").text
print(timer_t)
```

Output:

```
10.31

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But please understand that the text you are trying to extract is ever-changing and the frequency of change seems to be in milli-seconds, which makes it harder to grab the right value. The value that is grabbed is what the driver could capture at that moment in time.